# How to attribute the same data-id of an option tag to other element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have `<option>` tag with specific `data-id="x"` attribut. And I want to set the same attribute (data-id) of the option tag to the corresponding element (same html for example).

This is what I've done so far, yet I dont know why this is not working.

Can anybody help me on this?

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/z19u6eh9/4/)

I guess the problem is that I don't specify which $('.cityName) shall get the attribute but I dont know how to specify because $(this) will refere to the each...

### Here is the jQuery I'm using :

```
$('select option').each(function() {
   var value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id')); 
   var vals = (value+1); //This is optional
   if($('.productsDispo .cityName').text() == $(this).text()){
        $('.cityName').setAttribute('data-id', vals);
       //$('.cityName').append(vals);
    }
});
```

### And here is the HTML

```
<select id="citySelector">
    <option data-id="O">Bordeaux</option>
    <option data-id="1">Paris</option>
    <option data-id="2">Londres</option>
    <option data-id="3">Téhéran</option>
</select>

<!-- Product List -->

<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Bordeaux</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Londres</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Téhéran</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Paris</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: `<option class=".cityName"` should probably be without the dot in front of the class name `<option class="cityName"`

Comment: just to clarify: Having selected an item in the dropdown, you want the associated `<div>` to have the `data-id` attribute from the selected `option`?

Comment: @Andreas Yup indeed, fiddle edited

Comment: @Jamiec Actually I just want the element to have the same data-id as the option id if they are identical no :selected option in cause. My question is edited

Comment: Don't forget to add the radix to `parseInt`: `parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'),10);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `.each()` two times, one nested to the other. For every `<option>` you need to check every `div.cityName`.

One thing to keep in mind is that in the inner `.each()` the variable `this` refers to the `<div>` and not the `<option>`. And that is why I use the `$option` variable.

```
$('select option').each(function () {
    var $option = $(this);
    var value = parseInt($option.attr('data-id'));
    var vals = (value + 1);
    $('div.cityName').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == $option.text()) {
            $(this).attr('data-id', vals);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gxvqqm1z/2/)

Comment: Haaaa Realy cleaver !! So this is how to use 2 $(this) This shall be answering me perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you trying to do ...

```
 $('select option').each(function () {
        var opt = this;
        var value = parseInt($(opt).attr('data-id')) || 0;
        var vals = (value + 1);

        // Check the console Log 
        console.log("what you are excepting", $(opt).text());
        console.log("what is Returning productsDispo .cityName", $('.productsDispo .cityName').text());
        // if you check the console log you have to see you need to check for each 
        $('.productsDispo .cityName').each(function () {
            var item = this;

            if ($(item).text() == $(opt).text()) {
                $(item).attr('data-id', vals);
                //$('.cityName').append(vals);
            }
        });
    });
```

but if i were you make it on different to avoid each i add an attribute which is named as **data-bind-name** for  and html

```
<select id="citySelector">
    <option class=".cityName" data-id="O">Bordeaux</option>
    <option class=".cityName" data-id="1">Paris</option>
    <option class=".cityName" data-id="2">Londres</option>
    <option class=".cityName" data-id="3">Téhéran</option>
</select>
<!-- Product List -->
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName" data-bind-name="Bordeaux">Bordeaux</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName" data-bind-name="Londres">Londres</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName" data-bind-name="Téhéran">Téhéran</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo" data-bind-name="Paris">
    <div class="cityName">Paris</div>
</div>
```

and Jquery code is

```
$('select option').each(function () {
    var opt = this;
    var value = parseInt($(opt).attr('data-id')) || 0;
    var vals = (value + 1);

    // Check the console Log 
    console.log("what you are excepting", $(opt).text());
    console.log("what is Returning productsDispo .cityName", $('.productsDispo .cityName').text());
    // if you check the console log you have to see you need to check for each 
    $('.productsDispo .cityName[data-bind-name='+$(opt).text()+']' ).attr('data-id', vals);
            //$('.cityName').append(vals);

});
```

Comment: If OP was able to do that why not just set the id in attribute and not use script for this at all?

Comment: yeah you are right :D ..  to avoid filter and for each and js  ..  just bind is more logical ..

Answer (score 1):

Using just one `each` and selecting the corresponding city with `contains`:

```js
$("select")
    .change(function () {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        var city = $(this).text();
        value = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'), 10);
        vals = (value + 1);
        var item = $('.cityName:contains("' + city + '")');
        item.attr('data-id', vals);
        alert('data-id for ' + item.text() + ': ' + item.attr('data-id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="citySelector">
    <option data-id="0">Bordeaux</option>
    <option data-id="1">Paris</option>
    <option data-id="2">Londres</option>
    <option data-id="3">Téhéran</option>
</select>
<!-- Product List -->
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Bordeaux</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Londres</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Téhéran</div>
</div>
<div class="productsDispo">
    <div class="cityName">Paris</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This selector `$('.productsDispo .cityName')` will yield more than one element and hence you got to loop through it or jquery filter it to get the matched element and then set the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach using `data()` method which reads `data-` attributes as well as stores in element dataset as a setter

```
var $cityOptions = $('#citySelector option');

$('.productsDispo .cityName').each(function(){
    var $elem = $(this),  
         cityName = $.trim($elem.text()),
         $option = $cityOptions.filter(':contains('+ cityName +')');
    $elem.data('id', +$option.data('id') +1);
});
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/z19u6eh9/6/)</kbd>